# Como graficar en diagrama de caja o bigote

Tags: python, dataframe

Debo mostrar la distribución del número de hijos que tienen los desmovilizados según su
sexo. No se si estoy filtrando mal o he entendido mal el enunciado al momento de realizar el filtro, o estoy estoy haciendo mal el filtro.

[Los datos del datafame estan aqui](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O3LmXBidBq9GDmDS-SMkBBOhJTuvZqs_/view) por si es necesario

El código que tengo hasta ahora es esto

```
masculino = df['Sexo']=='FEMENINO'
filtroM = df[masculino]
media_masculino = filtroM['NumDeHijos'].mean()

masculino = df['Sexo']=='MASCULINO'
filtroM = df[masculino]
media_masculino = filtroM['NumDeHijos'].mean()
```

Ahora si, al momento de graficarla no se como graficarlo.

La grafica que se debe arrojar es asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Siento que estoy filtrando mal o haciendo el procedimiento mal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para generar un gráfico de cajas no necesitas filtrar nada. Pandas tiene el método `boxplot()` que lo hace todo por ti, con tal de que le pases los parámetros correctos.

En este caso:

```
ax = df.boxplot(column="NumDeHijos", by="Sexo", figsize=(6,6))
ax.set_ylabel("Número de Hijos")
ax.set_title("")
```

Lo que genera el gráfico:

[image: Resultado]

**NOTA**. Es un poco extraño el valor -2 en la caja "Masculino", pero es que efectivamente ese valor aparece entre tus datos. ¿Quizás haya que procesarlos antes para quitar datos absurdos?

Comment: Si es raro, tocaría que coger solo los que son mayores que 0, supongo que seria así, no ?. Bueno en si hay varios números negativos en la columna hijos, en ese caso como se organizaría, para que no apareciera el -2 ?

Comment: Ya logre ordenarlo para que no apareciera el -2, muchas gracias. Me ha sido de mucha ayuda para realizar y entenderlo.